# How to run a 68000 binary (68376 binary) on a modern version of embedded Linux?

Tags: virtualization, arm, embedded-linux, yocto-project

We are developing an embedded product, using Yocto Linux on an ARM architecture, a STM32 from ST.

For the current release, we aim to re-use, as quick and dirty as possible, the code originally written for a previous much older product, based on a 68376 microprocessor (which include toucan for CAN bus communication), on a custom board.

Is there any way to run the old 68376 binary as-is as much as possible, using some software emulator / virtual machine software? (I mean "emulator" as a software emulator, e.g. similar to the ones for vintage game consoles, or virtual machine, not an in-circuit emulator.)

The 60376 binary

- would have no GUI
- would have to communicate with another Linux process through serial ports (i.e. serial ports on the 60376 side, emulated, ideally implemented as sockets or something like that for the OS side)
- would have to communicate via CAN bus with other physical (not emulated) products (i.e. there would be a real CAN chip on the new custom board, and the original toucan code would need to work, accessing the real CAN chip somehow)
- access a retentive RAM

We are able to modify and re-compile the 68376 code, but we would like to do it as less as possible.

Comment: I wonder if QEMU would be a starting point but if you're talking about niche protocols, I suspect you'd end up rewriting stuff anyway

Comment: In principle, QEMU supports all the things. However, not in combination. All in all, this doesn’t sound like a realistic goal, sorry.

Comment: You might need hardware emulation, e.g., https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/hp/64700/hardware/E3458-97001_CPU32_Oct98.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjO57HvroiFAxV-EGIAHXc0AcUQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3NhAwjbYFK82ceVStPkPO2